# Firebase Cloud Firestore Security Rules for updateData FieldValue.delete() [swift]

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm removing the map element in the Test field.

Removing the "myID" key from the "Test"

```
self.db.collection("events").document("bkxREqn24JpdKYBLnBio").updateData([
            "Test.myID": FieldValue.delete(),
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error updating document: \(err)")

            } else {
                print("Document successfully updated")

            }
        }
```

How do I get the key of an item that I remove in the "security rules"? 
That's not how it works:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /events/{eventID} {
      allow write, update : if  request.resource.data.Test.keys()[0] == "myID"
    }
  }
}
```

although this rule works for the record

```
self.db.collection("events").document("bkxREqn24JpdKYBLnBio").updateData([
            "Test.myID": "MyText",
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error updating document: \(err)")

            } else {
                print("Document successfully updated")

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to only allow the write if the new document still contains `myID` value in the `Test` field, which is an array.

That'd be this in security rules:

```
allow write, update : if "myID" in request.resource.data.Test;
```

---

If you want to check if `myID` is being added, you'll compare `request.resource.data` with `resource.data`. So something like:

```
allow write, update : if   "myID" in request.resource.data.Test 
                      && !("myID" in resource.data.Test);
```